# Wrong icon for "Debug - Step Out" in VBE?

Tags: vba

The icon for "Debug - Step Out" in VBE seems like an arrow directing to the point just before a sub/cycle/etc., while as I can see this function is for fast forwarding to the point just after a sub/cycle/etc.

I find this icon confusing. What's wrong with my interpretation of it?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think you're thinking too much about this. Icon design is _hard_, give Microsoft's designers a break :)

Comment: I attached a screenshot JPG but I see as corrupted.  Can you see it?

Comment: Step Out is the opposite of Step Into. It takes you where Step Over would have taken you if you had pressed Step Over instead of Step Into. With nested routines, that would be exactly going "back up", which is correctly the opposite of the Step Into icon.

Comment: @GSerg While it would indeed be going "back up" it would _also_ be going "back up, and then go to the next statement".

Comment: @GSerg I can't really see Step Out as opposite of Step Into.  Anyway, I found here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/debug-menu the official doc. and Step Out is described with these words: "Executes the remaining lines of a function in which the current execution point lies. The next statement displayed is the statement following the procedure call. All of the code is executed between the current and the final execution points. Available in break mode only."  This make me still think that the backward direction of the arrow is misleading.

Comment: @6diegodiego9 Imagine you have `Sub Level1()` and `Sub Level2()`, and Level1 calls Level2 several times: `Sub Level1() : Level2 : Level2 : Level2 : End Sub`. If you press Step Into while in `Level1`, you will end up in `Level2`. If you press `Step Out` while in there, you will be back (up the stack) to `Level1`, on the next line relative to the one where you pressed Step Into (which is the same line you would have ended up on if instead of Step Into you had pressed Step Over). If `Level2` is located below `Level1` in your code editor, the metaphor of "going back up" becomes extra clear.

Comment: That's a point to muse about, but it's hardly a question that is on-topic here.

Comment: @GSerg I understand your point of view but I believe that it would be clearer if the Step Out arrow goes back down exactly where Step Over arrow ends. As you admit yourself, the Step Out and Step Over both end at the same point: the line after the procedure call.